# Merging 2 tables preserving the ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about merging a table with another preserving an ID on a database (I'm using MySQL). I have 2 tables, the first has and Item ID and a category and subcategory assigned to that ID. The second has a Item ID with all its characteristics like name and other variables. How can I merge those two tables in a way that the ID corresponds to the correct item in the new table (that's the difficult part I think)? Is it possible? 
[image: Please refer to this link to see a descriptive image of what I need to do, as I can't insert images directly]

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You mean, like a join?

Comment: Please post plain text instead of images, so we can copy and paste into answers and examples.

Comment: HINT:  INNER JOIN

Comment: @Hackerman yes sorry, I was thinking in joining them.

Comment: @Barman yes sorry I forgot to insert the text.

Comment: @Eric yes, thank you

Comment: If any of the answers below have solved your problem, kindly accept it as answer.

Comment: @Harshil Yes, I will try in a moment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very basic operation called `Inner Join`:

```
Select *
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.itemid = table2.itemid;
```

**EDIT:** As OP wants to create a new table with the fields return by above query and insert data into newly created table; following are the query to insert data once its created:

```
Insert into tablename
Select *
from table1
natural join table2;
```

**Note:** Make sure that the order and datatypes of columns in new table and in the result of above select query must be same.

Comment: Thank you @Harshii it worked just fine. Now I only have one table and that is what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. Just want to confirm one thing: Do you just want to display the merged results or want to create a whole new table with this merged data?

Comment: well, I wanted to create a new table and I'm working on phpMyAdmin so after a lot of failed attempts I discovered that you can export the results as another table and I opened that exported file with a text editor and modified some names (table name for example)  and then imported it and that automatically created a new table with the results of the operation that you shared. I just had to read the errors and start correcting things like "non existen category in field list" and some things like that. But I did it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Harshii the only thing that I noticed with your operation is that it keeps two itemid columns in the new table but I just deleted one

Comment: Yeah. My bad. In this case, instead of using `Inner join`, you should use `natural join`. `Natural Join` will join two table based on same column name and only keep one column and remove the duplicate column. For example, here both tables have `id` as common. Now `Inner Join` will keep `id` column from both tables while result of `Natural Join` will only contain one `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

This will Do:

select a.*,b.ItemName,b.ItemChar1,b.ItemChar2 from FirstTable a join select * from SecondTable b on a.ItemId=B.ItemId;

Use left join if some of the records are not there in the second table

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to create table from the combined results.  See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) page for details.

Basically you write and test the SQL query then CREATE TABLE table_name AS sql_query

```
create table new_item_table
as
select
  a.item_id,
  a.category,
  a.subcategory,
  b.item_name,
  b.item_char_1,
  b.item_char_2
from
  item_category a inner join item_char b on a.item_id = b.item_id;
```